# TYPO3 - Keep special chars in header

Tags: special-characters, typo3

How do I keep special chars in the header field in TYPO3?

As it is now it changes ß into ss. How can I keep the ß sign without writing codes?

Comment: Which header? The URL? Or the page title? Or the header of content elements?

Comment: Sorry, it is in the header of the content elements.

Comment: Which version of TYPO3 are u using?